# What's the point of white dye?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When you use [Bone Meal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bone_Meal) as a dye on [Wool](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wool), you just get Wool in return. Also, once Wool has been dyed another color, it cannot be dyed white again.

What's the point of using Bone Meal if it doesn't change anything?

Comment: Can you use Bone Meal on gray/black sheep?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bone Meal is also used to make Light Blue and Pink Dye (when mixed with a Lapis Lazuli and a Rose Red respectively). As to why you would need to make white wool, I don't know.

Comment: True, I didn't even think about Pink etc., only that it was a white dye and wool is already white

Comment: light grey is made from bone meal and grey as well

Comment: True - I excluded that from my answer because you can find that from the other colours of sheep.

Comment: Bone meal can also be used as a fertilizer as seen on the [Minecraft Wiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Bone_Meal).

Comment: If you have a color farm and accidentally lose all of your white sheep, you can dye another sheep white to repopulate the white pen.

Answer (score 8):

At least as of 1.4, Bone Meal applied directly to non-white sheep will turn them back to white.

In addition to being used to make other dyes, Bone Meal can also give you more white wool, **but it must be applied to off-color sheep, not the wool blocks themselves.**

*Tested on both red-dyed sheep and naturally occuring black sheep.